# Simple buffer overflow EIP overwrite not working

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, exploit

I would have asked this on stackexchange but Ive asked similar questions about this problem with not so much as a comment, I feel I will get better results here.

I have been trying to exploit this buffer overflow code on and off for a couple of weeks, I just don't know what the trick is!

I control EIP when overwriting with \x41's or pretty much any other character, but when I try to overwrite the return address with a valid address it SIGSEGV pointing to a different address, the address that catches the SIGSEGV does contain all my shell code and my 41's etc.

I have shutoff stack protection  and the stack is RWE, I have also checked for bad characters and found some shell code that does not contain any of the bad characters. If anyone could Help it would be appreciated since I wanna progress and the resources online don't seem to cover my problem. I have read Smashing the stack for fun and profit and understand the basics very minimal basics of assembly, I have read most tutorials online they're redundant for the most part, I have been reading any stackoverflow article I find relevant to my scenario, Please will one of you pros try to see what my problem is.

uname -a  output:

```
Linux windows 4.14.15-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 23 21:49:25 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void validate(char *pass) {
    if (strcmp(pass, "[REDACTED]") == 0) {
        printf("ACCESS GRANTED!");
        printf("Oh that's just idio... Oh my god!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Damn it, I had something for this...\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char password[200];
    printf("C:/ENTER PASSWORD: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    validate(password);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is Payload containing shellcode, 28 bytes:

```
payload = "\x90"*132+ret+shell+"A"*44
```

here is the shellcode:

```
\x50\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xf6\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5f\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05
```

Badchars are:

```
totalbad = "\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x20"
```

Comment: I think to get your shell code executed, you need to go and modify the `GOT` of `exit` in order for it to jump to the start address of `password` (where the payload will be) when your program is exiting. Since when the program is exiting and it calls `exit` it will resolve the address of `exit` using the dynamic loader. So in a brief explanation, `exit` will actually call `exit.PLT` which will use `exit.GOT` to get address of the actual `exit` that probably is in `libc.so` if you dynamically linked the executable. For statically linked, this is a whole different story. Hope this can help~

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So to modify this would i inject more code, or simply modify the source code then compile? also whats the explanation of why, When i overwrite EIP with A's or B's does it overwrite perfectly but when I try to overwrite with a return address it switches at least the last byte of the address? Thanks again!

Comment: Just to clarify that GOT is an abbreviation for Global Offset Table?

Answer (score 0):

So based on your story the problem is the return address. Your invalid return address is `0x41414141` which is `'AAAA'` and it does not contain NULL byte. Then you try your 'valid' return address that is contain NULL byte, so that `scanf("%s", password);` will stop read from stdin. Remember here `scanf` is reading string, which is NULL terminated, and if your return address contain NULL byte it will stop and it explain why your payload incomplete, shellcode and 'A'*44 is not copied. Remember that I only guessed the address contained NULL byte because based on your story the problems started when you changed the return address to a valid address.